# Deep learning libraries/software with good tutorials or examples

Tags: gpu, deep-learning

I am looking for deep learning libraries that have very good tutorials or examples, since I would like to learn by examples or doing tutorials even if these are not the best deep learning libraries. If they also run on GPUs much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/ uses Theano, which can run on a GPU.

Comment: Does it have good tutorials or examples that are easy to follow for beginners?

Comment: Yes sure. just follow the links on the page mentioned by Adrian. It starts with the classic Logistic Regression and cover deep networks like RBM and DBN.

Answer (score 2):

@Adrian already mentioned Theano.  The other big player here is Torch7, which runs on Lua and also has GPU integration.  There's a bit of discussion of their relative strengths and weaknesses [here](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/9403/a-good-deep-learning-library).

Answer (score 1):

The course from Hinton at https://class.coursera.org/neuralnets-2012-001/class is the best basic tutorial I found online. I think before you use tutorials from deeplearning.net, this would offer more insight.